# rep_1235 this object has been modified since the time it was read

Tags: workflow, informatica

I already read a lot of stuff on this message but the solutions did not fix my problem. I am using informatica 8.6.1

If I connect (I am alone, using informatic, nobody else), create a new workflow and add my job, when i press create, i directly got this message. 
`rep_1235 this object has been modified since the time it was read`

This is not normal, i have saved my job, closed the designer, and do all these workflow creation steps after. So my jobs should be up to date, there is no reason to get this message  I believe. But it keeps popin, and moreover, the changes i made are not reflected.

It is like the workflow sees an old version of my job, and i dont know how to update it, it doesnt work even if i create a new job just after connecting.

Do u have any idea of what I should do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really a solution, just a workaround
I copy my mapping in another repository, therefore, I don't have any history and I can start from fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Give relational connection

✓Right click on session -- refresh, Validate and save it

✓Disconnect And connect the folder